# React Native throws ' 6 stack frames were collapsed.' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the entire code

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <div className="container">
                <Nav  />
            </div>
            );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    topnav: {
        position : 'fixed',
        top : 0,
        right : 0
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Why does this error occur? Should import anything to support 'StyleSheet'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this import for the Style sheet:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
```

But another problem is that you are using a div. Div's are not available in React-Native, so you have to use other elements (like views).

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      }
    });

    return <View style={styles}><Text>I'm a Text</Text></View>;
  }
}
```